# What's the meaning of m-n relationship between two weak entities set?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, erd

I'm doing some exercises in my textbook, and meet this ER diagram:

[image]

I tried to convert above diagram into relational database schema, but I think I doesn't make any sense:

•   Assignments: assignmentNo, grade

•   Enrollments: assignmentNo

•   Students: studentID, takeAssignmentNo

•   Courses: dept, courseNo, offerAssigmentNo

Can you please explain how should I understand this diagram? What is its practical usage? How can I implement `score` relationship in SQL Server, or convert it into relational database schema?

Comment: You can maintain two tables to achieve this namely Course table=>student id,course id,dept name and Assignments table=>student id(pk),assignNo,grade.Here,student id is fk refred to course table and each student can do many assignments.So,there should be unique key constraint (studentid,assignNo).Grade specifies score obtained for each assignment.I hope,it helps you.

Comment: @MahaSwetha Thank you for your answer. Sorry to be rude, but I would ask on Yahoo! Answers if I only need the result. Can you please explain more information, as in my question (practical usage, proper way to do this kind of schema)?

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained the context in which you saw this diagram.  Were they explaining ER modeling and ER diagrams?  Were they explaining relational database design?  This may sound dense, but different textbooks use the same diagramming symbols for conceptual (ER) models and for logical (relational) models.

Comment: @WalterMitty It's in the section of how to convert ER diagram (in analysis step) into relational model (for design step).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Enrollments:  Student ID, Course No

Score:  Assignment No, Student ID, Course No.

Note:  Some designers frown on composite primary keys.  Not me.